# How to trim/remove leading/left white spaces from a text file using Windows Batch?

Tags: postgresql

I want to remove/trim the leading/left white space which are as a result of me hiding headers and footers from my PostgreSQL query using Windows batch. I am not sure whether these are white spaces or tabs.

My SQL query:

```
psql -d databasename -p portname -U username -t -f filename -o "C:\text.txt"
```

I am not aware of any other way to do this since my SQL is a multi line query and I am not sure if we can do this using `-c`.

Previous the result was something like this:

[image]

After removing the header:

[image]

So as you can see there is a white space here and I want to remove it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43989968/edit) your question and add your batch code !

Comment: hey hackoo,can you please look into this now or you need more clarity on what I am looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the `-t` and `-A` psql parameters:

- `-t` removes headers and footers from the results
- `-A` switches off aligned mode (which is most likely where your whitespace is coming from - alignment into columns).

So the command should look something like the following:

```
psql -d databasename -p portname -U username -t -A -f filename -o "C:\text.txt"
```

So, basically, you shouldn't need to modify the resulting file - you can modify your psql command to get results in a format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an hybrid script (batch\vbscript) to trim a string left and right :

```bat
@echo off
Set "VAR= abc@abc.com "
echo My Variable before the Trim Function VAR="%VAR%"
Call :Trim "%VAR%"
echo(
echo My Variable after the Trim Function VAR="%VAR%"
pause>nul & exit
::*************************************************************************
:Trim <String>
(
    echo Wscript.echo Trim("%~1"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"


for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do (
    set "VAR=%%a"
)

exit /b
::**************************************************************************
```